# Why is chromedriver not working in pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently trying to get chromedriver running on my mac in pycharm.

```
from selenium import webdriver
    import chromedriver_autoinstaller
    chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()
```

However, despite having chromedriver already installed, pycharm cannot find the module. How can this happen?

I already tried it out in VS Code but I have the same problem over there.